# dbus signal for volume up & down

Tags: 10.10, dbus

I recently upgrade to Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick Meerkat and to my dismay, the mediakeys "volume up" and "volume down" do not send Dbus signals anymore... how can I add these back?

Thanks!!

**Update:** it seems that under some circumstances (which I don't know exactly yet), the DBus signals start working again. It is as though when a certain application (TBD) is executed, the dbus signals are re-activated.

Comment: If you find intermittently functional software in Ubuntu, then that's a sure sign of a bug. File one on launchpad.net. This site is for questions and answers, for not bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem:  the service **HAL** isn't running. To start, use:

`sudo hald --daemon=yes`

Comment: Would you accept your own answer, as that what worked for you. See http://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

Try opening `Keyboard Shortcuts` (System -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts or <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> `gnome-keybinding-properties`) and reassigning the Volume Up and Volume Down keys.

Comment: ... to what? from "XF86AudioLowerVolume" to ?